# What are the cardinalities of the similarity classes of matrices over a finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, finite-fields

Similarity of matrices forms an equivalence relation. The set of linear maps between two finite dimensional vector spaces over a finite field is finite. Is there a combinatorial formula for the cardinalities of the equivalence classes?